# Is analytics.js being pulled in twice?

Tags: google-analytics

I enter a legacy codebase that has their analytics setup already. I am a bit new to Google Analytics but in our codebase, analytics events are pushed into a `data_layer`array on the `window` and Google Tag Manager (GTM) consume it at some point. I notice that on my network tag (and when running the GA debugger tool) it appears `analytics.js` is called and initialized twice. One from gtm.js where we initialized somewhere in our codebase but the other initiator is from https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js. I look all over the codebase and it doesn't appear this link is called anywhere and when I view the page as a rendered page, I do see two script tag calling for this script.

Is this normal or am I definitely missing a init function somewhere?

[image: image of network tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal when your website is HTTP not HTTPS. You can see the first call has a 307 status code which is for temp-redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. It is not being loaded twice.

GTM.js loads analytics.js and that is normal.